# How to access "base" in Discriminated Union method override?

Tags: f#

I have a DU and I'm overriding the Equals method. Based on the current DU value, I would like to call the base equality method or my custom one. However, it's not letting me access "base". Any idea on how to work around this?

```
type Test =
    | A of string
    | B of int64

override this.Equals(other) =
    let other' = other :?> Test
    match other' with
    | A str -> str = "a"
    | B i -> base.Equals this other //how do I do this?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First,** any F# discriminated union will have `obj` as base class, so just use `obj.Equals`.

**Second,** `Equals` is a .NET method, not an F# function, so its arguments must be given in a tupled form - i.e. `Equals(x,y)` instead of `Equals x y`.

**Finally,** if you implement a custom `Equals`, you also need to add `[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]`

So:

```
[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]
type Test =
    | A of string
    | B of int64
    override this.Equals(other) =
        let other' = other :?> Test
        match other' with
        | A str -> str = "a"
        | B i -> obj.Equals(this, other)
```

Comment: Can you also explain why the attributes are needed?

Comment: @glennsl By default all F# types get structural equality and structural comparison. If you're implementing your own, you need to turn off the standard one. The compiler will refuse to compile without that attributes. Try it.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you :) I ask mostly because I think the answer would be better if it explains why seemingly arbitrary actions need to be taken. Follow-up question: Is this just for performance reasons, to avoid an expensive virtual call when not necessary, or are there other reasons as well?